# use win32gui to capture grayscale screen

Tags: python, windows, win32gui

I use the following code to capture a window screen in python:

```
def get_screenshot(self):

    # get the window image data
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    
    # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
    #dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)


    # free resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    # drop the alpha channel, or cv.matchTemplate() will throw an error like:
    #   error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() 
    #   && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
    img = img[...,:3]

    # make image C_CONTIGUOUS to avoid errors that look like:
    #   File ... in draw_rectangles
    #   TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
    # see the discussion here:
    # https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14866#issuecomment-580207109
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
    return img
```

I took the code from some YouTube tutorials and the code works perfectly.

However, I'm trying to convert that image into grayscale so I could later use it for Homography without any success.

I tried to use things like `cv.cvtColor` but nothing worked.

Is there any way to make it grayscale right on the capture?

Thank you

Comment: You can convert an RGB value to a grayscale value via `0.3*R + 0.6*G + 0.11*B`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pillow package img.convert() function to convert to graystyle

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('download.png')
imgGray = img.convert('L')
imgGray.save('test_gray.png')
```